# WMI Win32_OperatingSystem OSProductSuite gives incorrect value on Windows XP

Tags: c#, c++, windows-xp, wmi

There is the following C# code that uses WMI to get OsProductSuite value from [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) and the analogous wSuiteMask using [WinApi function GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

        var name = query.Get()
            .OfType<ManagementObject>()
            .Single()
            .GetPropertyValue("Name");

        Console.WriteLine("Name from WMI = {0}", name);

        var suite = query.Get()
            .OfType<ManagementObject>()
            .Single()
            .GetPropertyValue("OSProductSuite") ?? "<NULL>";

        Console.WriteLine("Suite from WMI = {0}", suite);

        var info = new OsVersionInfo()
        {
            OSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OsVersionInfo))
        };
        var gotVersion = GetVersionEx(ref info);

        Console.WriteLine("GetVersionEx gotVersion = {0}", gotVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("GetVersionEx ErrorCode = {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        Console.WriteLine("Suite from GetVersionEx = {0}", info.SuiteMask);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetVersionEx(ref OsVersionInfo osVersionInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct OsVersionInfo
{
    public int OSVersionInfoSize;
    public int MajorVersion;
    public int MinorVersion;
    public int BuildNumber;
    public int PlatformId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szCSDVersion;
    public short ServicePackMajor;
    public short ServicePackMinor;
    public short SuiteMask;
    public byte ProductType;
    public byte Reserved;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:** On all OS after XP both WMI and `GetVersionEx` report correct `OSProductSuite` value. But on Windows XP the `OSProductSuite` from WMI is null.

I originally considered that it is a problem in .NET wrappers for WMI, so I have shamelessly adapted the C++ code from [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx) to do the same thing (the changes are in the step 7):

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
         _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
         NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
         NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
         0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
         NULL,                    // Security flags.
         0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
         0,                       // Context object 
         &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
         );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the OSProductSuite property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"OSProductSuite", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wcout << L"Failure in WMI";
            return 1;
        }

        wcout << "Variant Type of OSProductSuite from WMI = " << vtProp.vt << endl;
        wcout << "OSProductSuite from WMI = " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    OSVERSIONINFOEX info;
    info.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

    auto gotVersion = GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&info);
    if (!gotVersion)
    {
        wcout << L"GetVersionEx error is " << GetLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << L"wSuiteMask from GetVersionEx = " << info.wSuiteMask;

    wcin.peek();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed. 
}
```

But the variant type of the `OSProductSuite` is `VARENUM::VT_NULL (1)`, so it seems that the issue is with WMI itself. So, it is some XP issue with WMI, isn't it?

**P.S.:** While it is possible that there is some problem with XP distributives I used, or the issue stems from the fact that both machines are virtual (VmWare and SCVMM), it nonetheless seems rather doubtful.

Comment: Windows XP is long dead, so who is gonna fix that?

Comment: @LexLi I understand, but it still has [11% market share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0). I just want to be sure that it is truly a defect and not some configuration (distributive) issue.

Comment: @LexLi, no, it is not dead. Some people, particularly the older generation had difficulties in learning how to use a computer and their learning curve happened to be active while Windows XP was still a new thing. Now, you will not really be able to convince those, who remember very intensively the pain of learning how to use a computer to learn a new operating system because you claim the one they use is dead. They will see that the programs they are using are still working and will ignore your arguments.

Comment: Well, I'd like to know the reason behind those downvotes. Is it disgust to those who still have to support older OS? Or is there something wrong with this question? Not that those downvoters will explain, just...

Comment: @EugenePodskal, these are down-votes which are difficult to be explained. I encountered such down-votes in my own questions before, even though I have searched for answers, did not find and then asked eloquently, explaining the expectations, the problems, described what I have tried, how it failed and have even given examples. Even though I have made great effort into describing a problem, sometimes I end up being down-voted without explanation. There is nothing wrong with down-votes if they have a purpose, but purposeless down-votes are unnecessary.

Comment: I call those voters downvote-demons. Anyway, I will support your question, even though I do not know the answer, I consider it to be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as most of the WMI classes [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) is declared to have

> Minimum supported client     Windows Vista

and

> Minimum supported server     Windows Server 2008

Thus they are **officially** not guaranteed to work correctly or provide full capabilities on older OS.